# Fibonacci sequence Random Walk

Tags: random-variables, random-walk

Produce a sequence of random variables $\left\{X_{n}\right\}_{n \geq 0}$ as follows: Let $X_{0}$ and $X_{1}$ be some fixed constants. For $i>1,$ let $X_{i}=X_{i-1}+X_{i-2}$ with probability $1 / 2$ and $X_{i}=\left|X_{i-1}-X_{i-2}\right|$ with probability $1 / 2$

1. Suppose that $X_{0}=0$ and $X_{1}=1 .$ Find the probability
   $$\mathbb{P}\left(\exists n \text { such that } X_{n}=3 \text { and } X_{i} \neq 0 \text { for all } 1 \leq i<n\right)$$
   (This is the probability of the sequence $\left\{X_{n}\right\}$ reaching 3 before returning to the starting point $\left.0 .\right)$
2. Now suppose that $X_{0}=1$ and $X_{1}=2 .$ Find the probability
   $$\mathbb{P}\left(\exists n \text { such that } X_{n}=X_{n+1}=1\right)$$

I have no idea and can anyone help me?

Comment: I think I get it and have an idea. Imagine you are playing the roulette and you have certain amount of chips and you always bet 1 chip. After a certain amount of bets you have a certain probability of going bankrupt, well now imagine, that instead of betting always the same amount you have a variable amount, if for a given i you have $x_{i-1}=0$, $x_{i-2}=0$ then x_i and onwards will be all zero. Otherwise you have a probability of 1/2 of going one step foward and a probability of 1/2 of going one step backwards in the Fibbonacci sequence 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ....